# What are the significant changes with the revised Unearthed Arcana Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana

Wizards has posted [a revised version of the Ranger class](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf).

I read through some of the changes, but I'm not good at reading stuff side by side to understand all of the nuances that have changed and why the changes are considered better.

What all has changed, and why is this considered to be better?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, just go read it; it is worth the read.

The following are the major changes.  But there are others I'm sure I missed.

### Base Class Changes

- Favored Enemy and greater favored enemy separated out. With different creature type lists.
- Favored Enemy now adds a +2 to damage, and greater favored enemy +4.
- Natural Explorer is any natural terrain (without a definition for what natural terrain is) instead of having to pick a favored terrain.
- Natural Explorer gives a lot of new benefits like advantage on initiative and advantage on attack on an enemy that hasn't gone yet.
- Remove Extra Attack from the base ranger, and moves it instead to the subclasses (except Beast Conclave, which gets its own similar feature).

### Subclasses (now called Ranger Conclaves)

#### Beast Conclave

- Changed the beast companion list.
- Beast gets own turn.
- Beast can attack on its own turn w/o giving up ranger's action.
- Beast abilities gained are completely changed.
- Same beast can be brought back to life (at half cost) even if completely destroyed.

#### Added Subclasses from previous UA

- Hunter
- Deep Stalker

Comment: @V2Blast - Natural Area is mention in the mechanics of the class, so I edited out your flavor text comment but added a note that "natural area" isn't defined.  Otherwise thanks for the edit on the names of the Subclasses.

Comment: It mentions the "navigating the natural world" and "navigating the wilderness" in the feature description, but it doesn't say the benefits of the feature apply only in nature/the wilderness. The first three bullet points are preceded by "This grants you the following benefits:" - not "This grants you the following benefits when you are in natural terrain". You are right that the first sentence isn't *necessarily* just "flavor text", but it also has no mechanical impact on the benefits of the feature as written.

Comment: The same goes for the other benefits of the feature; the only stated restriction is that you gain those other benefits when traveling for an hour or more.

Comment: Related: [Unearthed Arcana Ranger: Does Natural Explorer apply all the time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91764/unearthed-arcana-ranger-does-natural-explorer-apply-all-the-time)